# PyQt5 Signals and Slots 'QObject has no attribute' error

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qt-signals, pyqt5

I have been trying to find a way to update the GUI thread from a Python thread outside of main. The [PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html) on sourceforge have good instructions on how to do this. But I still can't get things to work.

Is there a good way to explain the following output from an interactive session? Shouldn't there be a way to call the emit method on these objects?

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
>>> obj = QObject()
>>> sig = pyqtSignal()
>>> obj.emit(sig)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QObject' object has no attribute 'emit'
```

and

```
>>> obj.sig.emit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QObject' object has no attribute 'sig'
```

and

```
>>> obj.sig = pyqtSignal()
>>> obj.sig.emit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'emit'
```

Comment: same as here: [PyQt5 in what module is the emit method found?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581506/pyqt5-in-what-module-is-the-emit-method-found) - only __bound__ signals have an `emit` method. (`obj.sig = pyqtSignal()` is still an unbound signal)

Comment: @mata: Yes, I was taking these examples from the PyQt5 docs at sourceforge. As you [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581506/pyfqt5-in-what-module-is-the-emit-method-found), the emit method is for a bound signal, ie it is a member of a class that inherits from QObject. I didn't realize that I wasn't doing that in the interactive session pasted above.

Comment: @ mata: Just curious, what would be the utility of **obj.sig = pyqtSignal()**, as in the third example above?

Comment: `obj.sig = pyqtSignal()` assigns an unbound signal to an object instance - which doesn't make much sense. Signals need to be declared on a class, they're then bound when they're looked up on the instance - they're [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) in PyQt and descriptors only work as such when declared on a class.

Comment: Thanks this is going to be helpful for the project that I'm working on. Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Following words and codes are in [PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).

New signals should **only be defined in sub-classes** of QObject.They **must be** part of the class definition and **cannot be** dynamically added as class attributes after the class has been defined.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal

class Foo(QObject):

    # Define a new signal called 'trigger' that has no arguments.
    trigger = pyqtSignal()

    def connect_and_emit_trigger(self):
        # Connect the trigger signal to a slot.
        self.trigger.connect(self.handle_trigger)

        # Emit the signal.
        self.trigger.emit()

    def handle_trigger(self):
        # Show that the slot has been called.

        print "trigger signal received"
```

Comment: Wow, more than a year later! Answer accepted (even though question was cleared in the comments above).

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you implement `__init__` on your subclass of `QObject` you also have to call the superclass `__init__`