# PyQt5 in what module is the emit method found?

Tags: pyqt, qt-signals, pyqt5

It would be helpful somebody run this code for me as a sanity check.

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
>>>for i in dir(pyqtSignal):
...    if i == 'emit':
...         print(True)
...
>>>
```

Is true returned for anyone else? Note that with a QObject import from PyQt4:

```
>>> from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject
>>> for i in dir(QObject):
...     if i == 'emit':
...             print(True)
... 
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pyqtSignal`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal) is not a signal, it is a factory function for creating signals, so of course it doesn't have a `emit` attribute. It just returns a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), which when bound to a QObject instance will return the actual signal object. That means only a *bound* signal will have an `emit` method.

The `QObject.emit` method is a relic from times before new style signals were introduced in pyqt, and now [has been removed](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#old-style-signals-and-slots). Just use the `emit` method on the bound signal to emit it:

```
class SomeObject(QObject):
    someSignal = pyqtSignal(...)

instance = SomeObject()
instance.someSignal.emit(value)
```